Poetry installs `--without` group
I'm using poetry to handle my project dependencies.
Here is an example of my pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "My project"
authors = ["mail@gmail.com"]


[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.11"

[tool.poetry.group.ssh.dependencies]
my-private-project1 = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/myorg/myrepo1.git", rev = "main" }
my-private-project2 = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/myorg/myrepo2.git", rev = "main" }


The problem arises when I try to install this project within a Dockerfile, poetry version is 1.8.3 which is the last update so far.
I specially set a group called ssh so I can skip the install of this packages and do it by my own because poetry can't handle properly nested private repositories (or I couldn't find the way).
The command that I'm using within the Dockerfile:
poetry install --without ssh

That command fails with error message:
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Does anyone know what would be the best approach to directly ignore those ssh dependencies but still defining them in the pyproject?
I tried commenting and uncommenting the ssh group, whenever I comment the ssh group and then delete the --without ssh argument from the command, the Dockerfile builds correctly.

Include the poetry.lock in your docker image. Than poetry will not try to resolve the dependencies.

Even though I include poetry.lock I receive the same error.

Maybe a workaround, I do not know what it is worth... export as requirements.txt without the ssh group and install with pip and requirements.txt inside the docker image

I already install the private requirements with a custom bash script through ssh, but I still want to define them in my pyproject so I can set up the development environment.

Cross-Posted at https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/9545
